# dll Not Found After Build and Upload to Server to Run

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2012

we're trying to use a dll given to us by a different company, and on all development computer this dll is found fine and runs properly, but once we try to do the final build and publish it on one of our servers, the outside dll that we're usin gfrom this company is unable to be found and leads to the program crashing, any ideas for solutions and/or causes?

Comment: Hi, did you try to change dll local copy property to true?

Comment: I hope 'Copy Local' is set to true for this DLL before building?
Do you see this DLL in Bin folder after build?

Comment: copy local is set to true, so that is not the issue

Comment: yeah, it's set to true

Comment: Something in your build configuration is omitting the file. As a workaround you should be able to manually copy/paste the DLL.

Comment: the dll is already manually in the same folder as the built .exe that we're using for testing and it's still not finding it